How to Implement Conditional Statements within an Objective Function in CVXPY
I want to clarify that this is a follow-up question to one where we resolved an issue I was having with the max atomic function in CVXPY (Convex Function in CVXPy does not appear to be producing the optimal solution for a battery in an electircal system). With that solved, I am now encountering problems with the sum atomic function in CVXPY.
For context, I am optimizing a battery system (1 MWh) alongside a solar power system (200 kW nameplate capacity) to reduce electricity costs for a commercial building. This question focuses solely on the energy costs, which, in terms of the objective function, is the sum of the entire function
Problem Description
I am struggling to create a sophisticated objective function using atomic functions in CVXPY that applies different rates to P_G​ (the grid power) based on whether P_G​ is positive (importing power) or negative (exporting power). For example, say my objective function is cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.matmul(alpha, PG))), I want  alpha[0] to be 0.0755 when P_G is negative, and 0.3775 when P_G is positive. P_G is a variable that the optimization will solve, but the polarity of P_G is unknown when the objective is written.
Background
When I ran my function and examined the output, I noticed that the optimized solution seemed to export a substantial amount of electricity during high cost times and did not reduce electricity consumption during other times as expected (Figure 1). This led me to believe that the optimization function assumes exporting energy to the grid negates the cost of any energy imported from the grid using the same rate (within the same cost period).
Figure 1: Energy Charge Optimization (P_G is the same as Load after Optimization)

After further inspection, this actually makes sense. When I multiply the optimized load with alpha sum(alpha * P_G), I get -217.3, and when I maximize the same code instead of minimizing it, I get 185.5. Please correct me if my reasoning is wrong, but I suspect that the optimization function assumes that exporting energy to the grid (when load is positive) has the same value as importing energy from the grid. This is not always the case.
Objective
I want to differentiate between import and export rates to reflect real-world scenarios where these rates are different. The goals are

Use a specific import rate while having a zero or different export rate to prevent the optimization from exporting large amounts of power unnecessarily.
Reflect actual energy pricing where import and export rates are distinct.

Pseudocode
Simple matrix multiplication code:
alpha = [[0.0755, 0.0755, ... 0.1079 ..., 0.0755, 0.0755], [0.03, 0.03, ... 0.5 ... 0.2, 0.2]]
temp = []
alpha_i = lambda P_G, alpha, i: alpha[0][i] if P_G[i] < 0 else alpha[1][i]
for i in range (n):
  temp.append(cp.multipy(alpha_i(P_G[i], alpha, i), P_G[i], del_t[i]))
obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(temp))

# Constraints and the rest of the code

Rate function code:
def get_rate_from_time(time, rate = "import_rate"):
  # function obtains rate from a timestamp accounting for rate changes throughout the day and seasonal changes  
  return rate

def get_alpha(P_G, time):
   if P_G < 0:
     get_rate_from_time(time)
   else:
     get_rate_from_time(time, rate = "export_rate")
temp = []
for i in range (n):
  temp.append(cp.multipy(alpha_i(P_G[i], time), P_G[i], del_t[i]))
obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(temp))

# Constraints and the rest of the code

Question
How can I implement this objective function in CVXPY, considering the conditional rates based on whether P_G​ is positive or negative?
This is simple to do in python, but I am not sure how to utilize conditional statements in CVXPY, if it is even possible. Are there alternative approaches or workarounds in CVXPY to achieve this? Also, another problem I am having is the random peak for the last interval. I am not sure why that is happening.
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Example Code from Background
import sys

# Import libraries needed
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 

# One day of 15-minute load data
load = [36, 42, 40, 42, 40, 44, 42, 42, 40, 32, 32, 32, 32,
        30, 34, 30, 32, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 30, 32,
        32, 34, 54, 62, 66, 66, 76, 76, 80, 78, 80, 80, 82,
        78, 46, 104, 78, 76, 74, 78, 82, 88, 96, 84, 94, 92,
        92, 92, 92, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
        100, 100, 86, 86, 82, 66, 72, 56, 56, 54, 48, 48, 42,
        50, 42, 46, 46, 46, 42, 42, 42, 44, 44, 36, 34, 32,
        34, 32, 34, 32, 32]

# One day of 15-minute solar data
solar = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         2, 6, 14, 26, 46, 66, 86, 104, 120, 138, 154, 168, 180,
         190, 166, 152, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200,
         200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 190, 178, 164, 148, 132, 114, 96,
         76, 58, 40, 22, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# One day of 15-minute rate data
num_day = 1
alpha = [0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755,
       0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755,
       0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755,
       0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0874,
       0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874,
       0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.1079,
       0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079,
       0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079,
       0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079, 0.1079,
       0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874,
       0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874,
       0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0874, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755, 0.0755]
# Declare Parameters
eta_plus = 0.96  # charging efficiency
eta_minus = 0.96  # discharging efficiency
Emax = 900  # SOC upper limit
Emin = 200  # SOC lower limit
E_init = 500  # initial state of charge
P_B_plus_max = 200  # charging power limit
P_B_minus_max = 200  # discharging power limit
opt_load = load  # declaring optimal load
n = 96  # declaring number of timestpes for each optimization
del_t = 1 / 4  # time delta
d = 1  # int(len(load) / n ) # number of days

# Declare the arrays for the data outputs
pg = np.array([])
psl = np.array([])
eb = np.array([])
pbp = np.array([])
pbn = np.array([])
for i in range(d):
    # Declare constraints List
    cons = []
    # Pull solar and load data for nth day
    P_S = solar[int(n * i): int(n * i + n)]
    P_L = load[int(n * i): int(n * i + n)]

    # Declare variables
    P_G = cp.Variable(n)  # Power drawn from the grid at t
    E_B = cp.Variable(n)  # Energy in the Battery
    P_B_plus = cp.Variable(n)  # Battery charging power at t
    P_B_minus = cp.Variable(n)  # Battery discharging power at t
    P_SL = cp.Variable(n)  # Solar power fed to load at t

    obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.matmul(alpha, P_G) * del_t))

    for t in range(n):
        # First iteration of constraints has an inital amount of energy for the battery.
        if t == 0:
            cons_temp = [
                E_B[t] == E_init,
                E_B[t] >= Emin,
                E_B[t] <= Emax,
                P_B_plus[t] >= 0,
                P_B_plus[t] <= P_B_plus_max,
                P_B_minus[t] >= 0,
                P_B_minus[t] <= P_B_minus_max,
                P_SL[t] + P_B_plus[t] / eta_plus == P_S[t],
                P_SL[t] + P_G[t] + P_B_minus[t] * eta_minus == P_L[t],
                P_SL[t] >= 0
            ]
        # Subsequent iterations use have the amount of energy from the battery calculated from the previous constraint
        else:
            cons_temp = [
                E_B[t] == E_B[t - 1] + del_t * (P_B_plus[t - 1] - P_B_minus[t - 1]),
                E_B[t] >= Emin,
                E_B[t] <= Emax,
                P_B_plus[t] >= 0,
                P_B_plus[t] <= P_B_plus_max,
                P_B_minus[t] >= 0,
                P_B_minus[t] <= P_B_minus_max,
                P_SL[t] + P_B_plus[t] / eta_plus == P_S[t],
                P_SL[t] + P_G[t] + P_B_minus[t] * eta_minus == P_L[t],
                P_SL[t] >= 0
            ]
        cons += cons_temp
    # Solve CVX Problem
    prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)
    prob.solve(cp.GLOP, verbose=True, qcp=True)
    # Store solution
    pg = np.append(pg, P_G.value)
    psl = np.append(psl, P_SL.value)
    eb = np.append(eb, E_B.value)
    pbp = np.append(pbp, P_B_plus.value)
    pbn = np.append(pbn, P_B_minus.value)
    # Update energy stored in battery for next iteration
    E_init = E_B[n - 1]

    # Plot Output
    time = np.arange(0, 24, 0.25)  # 24 hours, 15-minute intervals

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(time, solar, label='Solar')
    plt.plot(time, [i * -1 for i in load], label='Load before Optimization')
    plt.plot(time, [i * -1 for i in pg], label='Load after Optimization')
    plt.plot(time, pbp - pbn, label='Battery Operation')
    plt.plot(time, [t*10000 for t in alpha], label='cost[x10000]')
    plt.plot(time, eb, label='Battery state')

    # Adding labels and title
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Demand (kW)')
    plt.title('Battery Optimization Output')

    # Adding legend
    plt.legend()

    # Display the plot
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

